# Finding Records with matching records in another table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 tables

Table 1

```
A | B  | C | D | E | F
a   Mi   2   1  4   001
b   Ma   3   1  4   001
c   NA   1   1  4   001
b   Na   3   1  4   001
d   Na   2   1  4   001
a   Mi   2    1  4   002
b   Na   3    1  4   002
c   Ma   1    1  4   002
d   Na   2   1  4   001
```

Table 2

```
A | B | C | D | E
a   Mi   2   1  4
b   Ma   3   1  4
c   NA   1   1  4
d   Na   2   1  4
```

OutPut :

```
F    |  D  
001    1
```

So columns A, B, C, D, E and F are all columns that specific conditions in them. Table 1 is the table with data that needs to be compare to data in table2. If all records in different columns except `F` match from Table1 to the records in Table2, only those records should be selected in the output.

Only 001 from column F is displayed because it has all the 4 rows with the same values in the same columns as given in Table 2. Records with value 002 in column F are not selected because they do not have all the rows in table 2. They do have all 4 rows but the record with b does not have all the same matching values.

The final result need not be the output i have mentioned. It could just be all those rows that match the rows given in Table 2. The output is just what the last step is . I can achieve that if i get all rows that match all the records in table 2 like by like.

Something I tried-

```
select count(A) over(Partition by A,B,C,D,E,F) as rw,* 
into #temp1 
from Table1

select sum(rw) as sm, F 
from #temp1 group by F

select F 
from #temp
where sm = (select count(A) from Table2)
```

One of the issues with this logic is that 002 can have 2-3 duplicated rows which might result in the count being equal to the count of rows in table2 .

Comment: Did you try with `EXCEPT`? Generate the needed row in a CTE with `EXCEPT` and then join it with the needed table.

Comment: 1) Why is the row (a   Mi   2    1  4   002) not selected in the output, although all A,B,C,D,E are same in table 1 and 2?

Comment: The explanation of the business rules here leave me scratching my head. Can you try to explain them more clearly?

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis the final output is that singular value of column F and D where the value in Column D has satisfied all records in table 2. The reason 002 is not selected is because all the records dont match table 2

Comment: @SeanLange So, rows in table1 have to match rows in table 2 as is. But, Table 1 can have duplicate rows and might not have the all rows in table 2. Only those values from F and D have to be considered which have all rows in table 2 as is. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: @Sami Can you please elaborate?

Comment: No this doesn't make sense at all. How do these rows correlate to each other if you are only looking at the columns F & D? Your sample is so obfuscated I think it is hindering your explanation here. Or maybe you just aren't explaining it.

Comment: I want the values for the column F & D that have all records that are in table 2. These rows are important for the selection of the values in columns in F & D. Also, as mentioned in my question if you can even provide me with the rows that match exactly to the rows (and all of them) in table 2 that works as well. I can pull the values from F & D myself.

Comment: Here's the deal. We don't have the knowledge of this project like you do. Saying all the records that are in table 2 is not making this clear. What does that mean? And certainly not helpful to just keep repeating the same vague explanation.

Comment: @SeanLange you dont have the knowledge as I do (regarding the project), all you have is the sample dataset and all I am trying to tell you is regarding the sample dataset.  Also, all the records in table 2 means all the row items in table 2. If you keep asking the same question the answer wouldn't be any different. Maybe explain what you did not understand and try to be more specific and I can probably tell you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a join of the tables and then `group by F`:

```
select t1.f, max(t1.d) d
from table2 t2 inner join (select distinct * from table1) t1
on t1.A = t2.A and t1.B = t2.B and t1.C = t2.C and t1.D = t2.D and t1.E = t2.E
group by t1.f
having count(*) = (select count(*) from table2)
```

I used `max(t1.d)` as it is not clear if the value of D is the same for each F.
See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=56a8abb03de37b6809189eec3fa1df81).
Results:

```
> f   |  d
> :-- | -:
> 001 |  1
```

If you want the rows from table1 that match the rows from table2, use a CTE:

```
with cte as (
  select t1.f
  from table2 t2 inner join (select distinct * from table1) t1
  on t1.A = t2.A and t1.B = t2.B and t1.C = t2.C and t1.D = t2.D and t1.E = t2.E
  group by t1.f
  having count(*) = (select count(*) from table2)
)
select t1.* from table1 t1
where 
  t1.f in (select f from cte)
  and exists (
    select 1 from table2 t2
    where t1.A = t2.A and t1.B = t2.B and t1.C = t2.C and t1.D = t2.D and t1.E = t2.E
  )
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c23ba2e5c24f8d4ae020a7e964a4a125).
Results:

```
> A  | B  |  C |  D |  E | F  
> :- | :- | -: | -: | -: | :--
> a  | Mi |  2 |  1 |  4 | 001
> b  | Ma |  3 |  1 |  4 | 001
> c  | NA |  1 |  1 |  4 | 001
> d  | Na |  2 |  1 |  4 | 001
> d  | Na |  2 |  1 |  4 | 001
```

If you want distinct rows use:

```
select distinct t1.* from table1 t1
```

instead.
Results:

```
> A  | B  |  C |  D |  E | F  
> :- | :- | -: | -: | -: | :--
> a  | Mi |  2 |  1 |  4 | 001
> b  | Ma |  3 |  1 |  4 | 001
> c  | NA |  1 |  1 |  4 | 001
> d  | Na |  2 |  1 |  4 | 001
```

Answer (score 1):

Disregarding the suspect row I mention in the comment, I think this is what you want:

```
select * 
from [Table 1] t1
where exists
(
    select 1 
    from [Table 2] t2
    where 
            t1.A=t2.A
        and t1.B=t2.B
        and t1.C=t2.C
        and t1.D=t2.D
        and t1.E=t2.E
)
```

Comment: You are not considering table 2 at all. How do you know the values that you are selecting have all the same rows that are present in table 2. this is just sample data, the table has more rows and obviously more records based on each distinct value of F.

Comment: obviously a typo, wanted to use table 2 inside the exists. Edited accordingly.

Comment: This gives all the records that have even one record in table 2. I want only those records that have ALL records in table 2.